# Explanation for a code needed : Appending the values to list in python

Tags: python, list, append

Anyone explain this please......

```
def f(i,list1=[]):

     list1.append(i)

     return list1


f(1)

f(2)

print(f(3))
```

Output: [1,2,3].

I cannot understand this, because everytime my list1 is initialized as a empty list.

Can anyone explain this??

Comment: read this article http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm

Comment: @PatrickHaugh - Absolutely.  I think anyone would be stumped on what to search for though.  I was...

Comment: Your `list1` is initialized not *everytime*, but **only once** - at the function's definition moment.

Answer (score 2):

You should not include the list creation in the argument declaration.

This is because the line that says `def f(i, list1=[]):` actually creates a new list when it gets to the `[]`.  This happens when the function is created.

Each time the function runs, it is re-using that same list object.

Think of it in terms of how the program runs, line by line.  In effect the `def` line ends up looking like this when it runs:

```
def f(i, list1=<a-new-list-that-I-just-created>):
```

And each time the function is called, the list1 default value is not a **new** list, but the list that was created when the function was defined.

I believe this is what you want, if you want to avoid this, is:

```
def f(i, list1=None):
   if not list1:
       list1=[]
   list1.append(i)
   return list1
```